# Launch a post after a click on a jquery dialog button?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, jquery-ui

can you guys tell me what's wrong with this code and why my delete button in my JQuery UI dialog box wont lunch the post to the controller url !

View HTML:

```
<a href="#" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="delete_button">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span> Supprimer les fichiers exportés</a>
<div class="dialog-message">
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Supprimer les fichiers exportès ?">
<p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>Les fichiers exportés vont être supprimés définitivement de votre disque. Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir le faire ?</p>
</div></div>
```

View JQuery:

```
$('#delete_button').click(function () {
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height: 200,
        width: 500,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Supprimer les fichiers": function () {
                /*$.ajax({async  : false, cache  : false, type   : "POST",
                url    : "index.php/site_ocr/delete_files",
                });*/
                $.post("index.php/site_ocr/delete_files");
            },
            Non: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that post URL is correct?

Comment: I've used window.open($("index.php/site_ocr/delete_files")); , same thing, i've got the button don't submit to the link bellow

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="javascript(void(0))" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="delete_button">
```

Hope this'll help.

Comment: Good answers accompany code samples with an explanation for future readers. While the person asking this question may understand your answer, explaining how you arrived at it will help countless others.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the answer was this !

```
"Supprimer les fichiers": function() {
      window.location.replace("<?php echo base_url('index.php/site_ocr/delete_files'); ?>");
      $(this).dialog("close");
    },
```

I hade to redirect to the action that I waned to proceed by a javascript `location.replace()` function :)